# error deploying Jersey+Weld webapp on Tomcat 8 or Jetty 9

Tags: tomcat, jersey, jetty, cdi, weld

I am getting the following error while deploying a webapp with jersey 2.2.6 and weld 2.4.6-Final

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.weld.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
        at org.jboss.weld.util.collections.ImmutableHashSet.<init>(ImmutableHashSet.java:78)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.collections.ImmutableSet.from(ImmutableSet.java:176)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.collections.ImmutableSet.access$100(ImmutableSet.java:43)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.collections.ImmutableSet$BuilderImpl.build(ImmutableSet.java:161)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle.createDeployment(WeldServletLifecycle.java:295)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle.initialize(WeldServletLifecycle.java:163)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener.onStartup(EnhancedListener.java:62)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ...
```

I can clearly see that method exists in the said class, but fail to understand why the error occurs.

Here is the relevant snippet from pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0-b60</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-weld2-se</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion> 
                <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
                <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x-servlet</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion> 
                <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
                <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and here is my web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>PIIApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.project.RESTService</param-value>
         </init-param>
     </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PIIApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <resource-env-ref>
        <description>Object factory for the CDI Bean Manager</description>
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>
            javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager
        </resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>
```

After removing the weld-servlet (uber jar) dependency and explicitly adding weld-core and weld-servlet-core, cdi-api-1.2 dependencies, i got a different error, as shown below:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ExternalRequestScopeConfigurator.init(ExternalRequestScopeConfigurator.java:84)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:359)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$1(ApplicationHandler.java:316)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:256)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.&lt;init&gt;(ApplicationHandler.java:282)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.&lt;init&gt;(WebComponent.java:335)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:178)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:370)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
```

Could someone explain me why i am getting this error or point me to a github link that is working (i tried deploying cdi-webapp example from jersey project, but it fails with HK2 related errors in tomcat)

Thanks,
Samba

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. Could you solve it?

Comment: although this is very old question, thought it may help someone in need. if i remember it correctly, JSF jars from the reference implementation are now dependent on websocket api, which is missing in google app engine web server. add that jar, the error should go away